# PHP hosted online - send UDP to local machine

Tags: php, tcp, udp

I'm trying to figure out how or if it's possible to have a php based site, which would be hosted online, and be able to send/receive UDP/TCP packets to devices on the users local network.

The goal is to have a website that my clients can navigate to over the www, where they have custom pages with buttons that can send UDP and/or TCP packets (not too fussy on which protocol right now) to devices that are on their local network, such as a button to turn off their projector or perhaps turn on lights.

Bridging the two networks is where I'm stuck

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but I don't believe this is possible. At least not directly. You're asking how to give the internet access to a local network. That would a serious security risk if it were possible. As you said, you'll need a bridge. Like a local server (that therefor has access to the local network), which bridges with the remote server. It doesn't have to be a server. It could be a program that connects with the remote server and does the job. But without a bridge, it's afaik just not possible, because the browser doesn't have access to the local network. Not even the local filesystem

Comment: That last bit came out wrong. Obviously the browser does have access to your local network. Just not that kind of access. It's not like I could write some code that sends a package to the browser and the browser distributes it across your local network. The server can deliver the package to the user. But it's up to the user what (s)he does with it after that. Just think about it. If it was possible, I'd be able to see which devices are connected to your network from my server. Goodbye privacy. It'd be like I can control your router..

Comment: So to answer your question: Each user needs a local server or program that controls the devices on their network. That server or program needs to connect to your webserver and listen for "commands". Server sends command A to local server / program. Local server / program performs task listed under command A received. Make sure your security is top notch for this though! If you get hacked, someone will be able to control a lot devices which could potentially be dangerous! Depending on what kind of devices are connected..

Comment: Agreed, yes security is a concern indeed. The configuration I am looking at is a very special circumstance whereby there are no "normal" devices on the network, only items that have specific ports open (no laptops, desktops, cellphones or anything normal in the slightest bit). That side (including the security aspect) is of absolutely no concern and we have that covered. My concern is just in bridging connections between the WAN and LAN.